# Why the size of base64-encoded string is larger than the original file

Tags: base64

My original PDF file size is around 24MB, however when I encode it to based64 string, the string size is around 31MB. I'm wondering why that is.

It is easy to understand for an image file since it may lose some compression, but it also happens to PDF or some other format files?

Comment: For the exact same reason that `9` in binary is `1001`, taking four times more space! You're converting from base-256 to base-64, that's gonna come with some space gain - typically 33% because base-64 isn't stupid and includes some re-packing of the data.

Comment: make sense, thanks @Niet the Dark Absol

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> just wondering why

Because Base64 has fewer meaningful bits per byte than a binary data format (usually 6 instead of 8). This is specifically so it can survive various textual transformations that binary data would not.

[Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) has a good diagram showing this:

[image]

As a text table *(sadly the GitHub-flavored markdown used by SO doesn't support tables with varying numbers of columns)*:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|   Text content  |               M               |               a               |               n               |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|     ASCII       |           77 (0x4d)           |           97 (0x61)           |          110 (0x6e)           |
|  Bit pattern    | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
|     Index       |           19          |           22          |           5           |           46          |
| Base64−encoded  |           T           |           W           |           F           |           u           |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note how the Base64 is only using the bottom six bits of each byte, and so "Man" ends up being four bytes long.

> It is easy to understand for image file since it may lose some compression

Just to be clear, Base64 encoding is lossless. When you decode it, you get byte-for-byte what you started with.

Comment: 4 bytes long? I count 3 bytes and 4 ASCI chars...

Comment: @AnnaKlein - On the wire in Base64, those 4 ASCII characters each take a byte, so it 4 bytes for the Base64 text. (Before any compression, of course, but compression is out of scope.)