# Why use Base64 encoding for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, base64

I've got a HTML file with embedded JavaScript like this:

```
<script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,LyohIGpRdWVyeSB2MS4xMS4z ... ></script>
```

I found out that it is like normal JavaScript but in [Base64 coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

I used https://www.base64decode.org/ to decode the JavaScript and found that it's just the jQuery library.

Now I wonder what the reason might be to encode jQuery in Base64 instead of just load it with a `<script type="application/javascript">`? Especially if it's even larger than the original text ([Why the size of base64-encoded string is larger than the original file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811673/why-the-size-of-base64-encoded-string-is-larger-than-the-original-file))!

Edit: Have a look at the script in: https://gist.github.com/kristian-lange/7605e6cd2c643313022eb796e15458fa.

Comment: Speculation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult (because inlining images that was saves you an HTTP request).

Comment: Read http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt

Comment: @Quentin What does Cargo Cult to do with inlineing of JS? And you could inline JavaScript without using Base64.

Comment: @Kris — Because people see people doing it for images "for performance" and then do the same thing for JavaScript without considering the standard approach for inline JS.

Comment: @underscore Thank you for your link, but could you please point to some lines to enlighten me. I'm just lost.

Comment: @underscore — That link doesn't seem relevant to the question at all.

Comment: Inlining JS as a data URI is not a common practise. I've never encountered it before. It's really a case of speculating about why some unknown author did something that seems quite silly … and that's more a matter of opinion than anything else.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, that might be the reason. Although a disappointing one. I expected something more technical. ;)

Comment: @Kris The simplest reason could be portability and escaping of the raw text of the strings within `javascript`. Additionally, approach does not require request for external resources. See also [Single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) . Can you include text of decoded `base64` string at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I added the source code. Decoded it's just the jQuery library. And I agree inlineing saves you one request - but why doing it in Base64?

Comment: @Kris _"but why doing it in Base64?"_ To avoid having to escape the string which comprises the `javascript`; in this case a version of the jQuery library. The original `base64` string could further be utilized, for example, within an additional embedded `document` within original document

Comment: @guest271314 But it's JavaScript. It's not necessary to escape JavaScript, isn't it? You could just put the whole code in between `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: Yes, the entire `javascript` could be placed within `<script></script>` tags. Depends on the expected result. `base64` offers consistent encoding of the text, which can further be utilized within additional embedded documents without having to possibly escape strings within source of original `javascript` text

Comment: @guest271314 Can you please give an example? It's still difficult to understand for me what you mean with 'additional embedded documents'. Do you mean additionally embedded within the Base64 encoded JavaScript?

Comment: _"Do you mean additionally embedded within the Base64 encoded JavaScript?"_ Yes, that is one possibility

Comment: @guest271314 But then again it wouldn't make sense for jQuery, would it?

Comment: @Kris Depends, trying to dig out a piece composed several years ago. jQuery was a variable within `javascript` encoded as a `base64` string - along with all images, with ability to export data from original `html` document and include jQuery within exported document.

Comment: @guest271314 sounds like dark magic to me :)

Comment: @Kris A basic example of embedding `base64` encoded  jquery within a current and document opened from current document http://plnkr.co/edit/QpbsKBjfCOtbApasZr29?p=preview

Comment: @Kris One of principles of spa is to include all necessary resources within text of initial document,  with ability to export same resources to other spa's without making external request. The spa can also be viewed or run locally, providing same experience as if user was online requesting external resources. `base64` provides consistent text format which can be exported, decoded without having to encode and decode at each step of process.

Comment: @guest271314 I looked at your example. It's great (and frightening - but I'm more of a Java programmer :) ). I definitely learned something today!

Answer (score 1):

Probably because people don't know how to use the proper encoding, and then prefer to use base64, which usually works even if the encoding is wrong.

For example, this should work:

```html
<script src="data:text/javascript,console.log('âàáäã')"></script>
```

However, if you use that in a UTF-8 file but don't tell the encoding to the browser, it might think it's something like windows-1252, and parse it as

```html
<script src="data:text/javascript,console.log('Ã¢Ã Ã¡Ã¤Ã£')"></script>
```

If you use base64, it will be

```html
<script src="data:text/javascript;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coJ8Oiw6DDocOkw6MnKQ=="></script>
```

And the browser will probably interpret it correctly, even if it attemps to read it using the wrong encoding.

Comment: Thanks, but then I could just use `<script charset="UTF-8"> and have it embedded in a readable fashion, couldn't I?

Comment: @Kris Yes, but I'm talking about people who don't know how to tell the browser which encoding they are using.

Answer (score 0):

Portability. It is not necessary to make external request that may or may not succeed.

Comment: As the OP said, why not just inline the script using the standard means?

Comment: @Quentin Again, from perspective here, without viewing the actual text of `javascript`, for portability. Some time ago composed a `data URI` piece which embedded `javascript` in a document as as `data URI`, which included further `document`s as `data URI`s. Attempting to escape strings of multiple levels of embedded `javascript` text would have been more challenging than converting text of `html`, `javascript` to `data URI` as `base64`. Essentially, the approach is to create a single page application; or spa which could also include embedded spa's, where text is escaped using `base64` encoding