# Is it possible to send file and json data as a single response to the client - Java Spring?

Tags: java, angular, spring-rest

I want to generate a response using `Spring rest`. This response should include an excel file and some json data. Also, I want to parse this response in Angular.

Comment: I'm not sure what a proper way would be but you could base64 encode the file and include it in a json response with your other json data.

Comment: If you have your file on a server, you can include in the response the url to download the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [E. Sundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3951400/e-sundin)
mentioned, it worked by base64 encoding on the server and sending a json which includes this base64 string and parsing the json in Angular like shown below -

**Java code** -

```
            byte[] bytes = null;
            String base64 = null;

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try {
                workbook.write(bos);
            } finally {
                bos.close();
            }
            bytes = bos.toByteArray();
            base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);

            Map<String, Object> resMap = new HashMap<>();
            resMap.put("failed", 12);
            resMap.put("attempted", 20);
            resMap.put("file", base64);

            return new ResponseEntity(resMap, HttpStatus.OK);
```

**Angular code** -

```
this.service.call().subscribe(data => {
  this.totalFailed = data.failed;
  this.totalUploaded = data.attempted;
  window.open('data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,'+ data.file);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Base64 encoding will work technically, however, beware, it will place an additional burden on:

- Server: computation time to actually encode the value
- Client: someone has to decode value, again it takes time/CPU resources
- Network, only because base64 encoded data by size is bigger (~30%) than an initial byte stream. See [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811673/why-the-size-of-base64-encoded-string-is-larger-than-the-original-file) and answer to understand why

In addition since one of the projects I worked on has this feature, it's very inconvenient to use JSON like this (copy and spread, etc.)

If it's an acceptable solution nonetheless, go for it, it will work and you won't lose the data or something.

However, there are other approaches:

Obviously - split the requests, may be given the considerations I've presented above you'll come to a conclusion that making two calls to the server, one of which will return JSON and other an excel file will work you better.

Using some kind of multipart mixed response, with this approach you get one call, however, it's not how to cope with this on the Client side, I don't know whether angular / browser in general support this.

Comment: Thanks for the details Mark. The problem with making two requests is that I will have to persist the excel file on the server before user requests for the file the second time. I wanted to avoid handling the persist and retrieve of the file from db or file system. I do not have much knowledge about multipart response and parsing in `Angular`.