# Base64 PDF string taking up too much space

Tags: pdf, webforms

We have a project that converts rtf to a base64 encoded pdf. Then that encoded pdf is written to a database. As you can imagine that database is ENOURMOUS! How else can we store a pdf in a database that has a much smaller footprint and still be able to display the PDF through a **web forms** web site??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811673/why-the-size-of-base64-encoded-string-is-larger-than-the-original-file Have you seen this yet?

Comment: Is the generated PDF is the same every time? Why not only store the text data and generate a PDF on-demand?

Comment: The pdf is not the same everytime

Comment: @MikeMurphy By "same every time" I mean, given the same rtf input, is the output always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you might be looking for is related to PDF compression. Base64 does not compress anything and as you have experienced, makes a bigger file size. There have been libraries that you can use for this and one is iTextSharp. [This might be an old post](https://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-pdf-compression.htm) and uses an older version of the library, but it should point you to the right direction.